# Getting "Split Screen or picture-in-picture is not supported for this app"

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

I am trying to support split screen feature in my app.

[image]

Target SDK is 27 currently

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myvestige.vestigedeal"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 46
        versionName "5.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

and added resizeableActivity to "true" inside manifest in application tag.

```
<application
        android:name=".activity.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/newicon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:resizeableActivity="true">
```

Still when I am sliding down with three fingers(manual screen-split), getting "**Split Screen or picture-in-picture is not supported for this app**".

Also attaching screenshots of error message I'm getting. **I am using vivo-v9(8.1.0) for the testing purpose which supports split screen**.

Please help me in finding what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: try to open your app manually from choosing from split screen instead of directly opening split screen from your app.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to find the solution of the problem. Split feature working perfectly in other devices(tested in Oppo F3, One plus 6 and Samsung j8) but not working in Vivo v9. I have reported the same to Vivo support team and they replied as

"**Kindly go to setting > smart split > it will work only those application which are showing there. I do understand your concern, but it will work on those application which is showing there.**"

Apps listed inside **setting > smart split >** in **Vivo v9** are Facebook, Whatsapp, Gamil etc... I am also attaching screenshots of the apps listed there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the OnMultiwindowsChanged function in the Main Actitivity it should get the job done

Comment: did you try changing the device.....all the apps can do the split screen in default...also try giving the app a layout for split screen

Comment: Yes its working in other devices. Checked in Opo F3 and in One plus 6. But still what is the issue with vivo v9?

Comment: as you are saying "try giving the app a layout for split screen"...please help me to do so

Comment: In the application manifest, you can declare what should be the size for each Activity refer the documentation:[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) go to Layout attributes in the documentation